# Loading data from a php page using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Gurus and other fella's, if anyone could help me with this.

**Scenario:**
The following page returns unique text string every time you call it.
http://projects.tk-fn.com/controls/advance_file_uploader/unique_id.php

I want to call this page from a HTML page and then load this character string in a container div.

I have wasted my entire weekend on this but can't get it working. Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is in different domain you can't use Ajax request :) but... you potentialy can sue iframe!

```
<iframe src="http://projects.tk-fn.com/controls/advance_file_uploader/unique_id.php"></iframe>
```

You can tried it out even here! just open console and type

```
$("body").html("<iframe src=\"http://projects.tk-fn.com/controls/advance_file_uploader/unique_id.php\"></iframe>");
```

Cheers!

Comment: Yeah! that was the main cause.

Comment: Even on the same site it was not working. I later re-wrote the code and it started working. Strange but this problem made me research the whole object in detail. 
I really appreciate your response. If you are interested in my code it is at: projects.tk-fn.com/examples/HTTPRequestObject.html